# web.config forms auth security not working

Tags: iis, forms-authentication, iis-8

This is my web config below.  All i'm really trying to do is deny all anonymous users to the entire site unless they have the cookie.  However, nothing I do seems to be able to make the security work.

I'm using anonymous authentication enabled with application pool identity
and forms auth with cookies.  The site always allows users in and it's driving me insane!

Thanks!

```
<configuration>
<location path=".">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Any and all help is welcomed!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to deny access to the whole site, then you don't need a location section. Just put the authentication and authorization sections directly in system.web, like so:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
....
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="120" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```